# c# arrays with counter controlled for loop

Tags: c#

Good day
I have have this assignment at school about a factious company that measures covid-19 temperatures. We are asked to design a c# program that will perform tasks with the stats.

The array of collected temperatures from 50 people:

```
double[] temperatures = new double[50] {36.7, 36.5, 36.6, 36.9, 37.0, 36.2, 36.4, 36.8, 37.2, 37.4,
                                        36.2, 36.6, 36.7, 36.9, 36.8, 36.7, 36.5, 37.0, 36.3, 36.7,
                                        37.6, 37.1, 37.8, 38.2, 36.7, 36.8, 36.5, 36.8, 37.1, 37.9,
                                        36.0, 35.5, 36.8, 36.9, 37.0, 37.8, 36.4, 36.8, 36.7, 36.1,
                                        37.2, 37.1, 38.5, 37.4, 37.9, 38.0, 35.9, 37.0, 36.7, 36.5};
```

Body Temperature Categories and Body Temperature Ranges (in Celsius)

Cold: Lower than 36.5 - Normal: From 36.5 to 37.4 - Hot: Higher than 37.4

Problem: find out how many element in the Array fall under 'normal' body temperature.

The required method to solve the problem is 'counter controlled for loop'.

Thanks in advance!

```
double normalTemp = temperatures[0];
double hotTemp = temperatures[0];
double coldTemp = temperatures[0];

for (double index = 0; index < temperatures.Length; index++)
{
    if (index >= 36.5 && normalTemp <= 37.4)
    {
        normalTemp = index;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Number of Normal Temperatures: {0}", normalTemp);
```

This is what I've tried, cant seem to find a way

Comment: What have you tried so far to get the count of low, normal and hot?

Comment: create a variable to keep track of the number of items, then, using a [`for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) or [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) loop, iterate over all the items and increment the variable if the current item is under the "normal" temperature.

Comment: FYI, downvotes are probably due to lack of research effort. They would likely be removed if you show what you have so far, and specifically where you are stuck.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service. We will happily help you fix problems with your code but you need to do the initial work and try to solve the problem on your own first.

Comment: @Jawad, I so far tried this strategy 
```
double normalTemp = temperatures[0];
            double hotTemp = temperatures[0]; 
            double coldTemp = temperatures[0]; 

            for (double index = 0; index < temperatures.Length; index++)
            {
                if (index >= 36.5 && normalTemp <= 37.4) 
                {
                    normalTemp = index;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Number of Normal Temperatures: {0}", normalTemp);
```

Comment: @Rufus ok thanks, let me try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking the temperature itself, but checking on the index of the array instead and in your declaration of the `double normalTemp = temperatures[0];` you are assigning the first value in the array which is incorrect.

```
int normalTemp = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < temperatures.Length; index++)
{
    if (temperatures[index] >= 36.5 && temperatures[index] <= 37.4)
    {
        ++normalTemp;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Number of Normal Temperatures: {0}", normalTemp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an obvious bug! You are iterating through indices of your array and then trying to use the index instead of the underlying array element which would be `temperatures[index]`. Also array index is an `int` so it's pointless to declare it as a `double`! So your criteria (the `if` block) should look like this after the fix:

```cs
if (temperatures[index] >= 36.5 && temperatures[index] <= 37.4)
{
  normalTemp++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        int normalTemp = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index < temperatures.Length; index++)
        {
            if (tempretures[index] >= 36.5 && tempretures[index] <= 37.4) 
            {
                normalTemp ++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Normal Temperatures: {0}", normalTemp);
```